# Database is not connected to my website build on ASP.Net

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got stuck in deployement of my website built using ASP.Net, C# and using sql server 2008 database. The problem is that website is working perfectly fine on localhost but it is not connecting with database when I hosted it on web, I know that the problem is in Sql server database in giving permission or something but I don't know exactly because the connection and user which I have created is exactly the same as I used while development and as soon as I deployed it on web the part which is not using database is working fine that is login page but when I enter username and password in the interface and hit login it does not go into database and pull the data, I mean it does not connect to database at all.

My question is that does it matters in accessing database from localhost and from web, Though I am still using My local computer for Coding and using the company"s database through VPN. This is first time I am deploying the website on web and I need some help, I know my way of asking question might ambiguous but please try to understand and if you have some question than please ask don't just ignore.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most frequent solutions:

- Enable TCP/IP protocol for sql server instance.
- Enable SQL Server Browser service.
- Open firewall ports.

More information:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: The database is the same and.. only websites locations are different? pointing to the same db?

Comment: yes, the database is the same. The only difference is my website working fine locally but not working on web